# how to get correct attribute for class Meta?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models, pgadmin

after running command python manage.py inspectdb, i am having following error

TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): ifsc,bank,branch,address,city,district,state

my model is as following

```
from django.db import models
class Banks(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'banks'

        name = models.CharField(max_length=49, blank=True, null=True)
        id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'branches'
        ifsc = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
        bank = models.ForeignKey('Banks', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
        branch = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
        address= models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
        district = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=26, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: model fields are supposed to be in  the model class, not it's `Meta` class. Also two definitions of `Meta` won't work... Is this really the output of `inspectdb`, or did you edit it to this way?

Comment: You should not specify the database fields in the `Meta` class, only meta options.

Comment: Inspectdb produced this? This sounds very strange, as it looks wrongly formatted/indented altogether. Did you modify the output of inspectdb? DId you redirect its output to a models.py file (i.e. `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`)?

Comment: two meta was the output of inspectdb. i jumbled things to figure out if i can get rid of error. thanks the solution you provided worked. @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: @jay `inspectdb` should not be giving such output (It should have given you 2 model classes with their own `Meta`)... Anyway if you are talking about the answer below it was given by Willem, not me, I only edited it a bit to remove some text that was mistakenly copied from the question, do accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: thanks for the help. i added two model classes and its working @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did the indentation the wrong way. Fields are specified at the class level, so:

```
from django.db import models

class Banks(models.Model):
    #↓ Banks class attributes
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    # ↓ Banks class attributes
    name = models.CharField(max_length=49, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'banks'
```

as for the second meta, this should belong to another model class.